# In Safari browser change event not fired when modifying the element's value inside input event handler

Tags: macos, safari, onchange, html-input, inputevent

While modifying the element's value inside input event of the input element , the change event is not fired in Safari browser.

I have use the below code block

```
`<input type="text" id="textid"\>

 <script\>
 var textcase = document.getElementById('textid');
 textcase.addEventListener('input', function(args) {
     document.getElementById('textid').value =document.getElementById('textid').value + "#";
 });
 textcase.addEventListener('change', function(){
    console.log('Change evet triggered');
 });
 </script\> `
```

Replication Procedure :

1. enter a value in the input element and focusout.
2. see the console window the change event was not triggered.

Expected behavior:

1. When modifying the element's value inside input event of the input element. the change must trigger in the safari browser.